# WordPress project setup - Trellis, Valet or Docker?

Tags: wordpress, docker

I want to start a new WordPress project with another developer. The decisions we made are:

- We want to use Bedrock as the WP structure
- we want to use Sage as the WP theme
- We put the project in a GIT repository

I now ask myself if we should use Trellis, Valet or Docker.

My personal opinion is that Trellis / Docker is a bit too much for a project with two developers working on it.  Additionally my experience with Vagrant is not very positive, as it was very slow when I used it. My favorite would be Valet, because it's so slim. The repository I would use is Beanstalk, from there I would trigger my deployments to my test and live system.

Additionally I am not 100% sure if my server to which I want deploy my project also needs Docker installed - does anybody knows that? And what happens when my server runs on Apache and not Nginx?

Answer (score 2):

Now that Docker has native Mac and Windows apps you wouldn't need Vagrant for local dev, and running a series of Docker containers is *much* faster than a full-fledged VM with Vagrant+VirtualBox. Right now I have MariaDB + PHP-FPM + Nginx + WordPress + PHPMyAdmin, and the whole thing is really fast relative to my previous experience with Vagrant. Faster as in: faster initial install, faster to start/stop, faster to make changes and have them reflected after a restart. I just replaced MySQL with MariaDB in a matter of minutes (mostly fumbling with having the proper syntax in my docker-compose file).

The beauty of Docker appears precisely when you want to switch components (say Apache vs. Nginx). In WordPress' case, they provide images on Docker Hub that either include Apache or PHP-FPM (in the latter case you just add a Nginx container to your stack).

That said I just got started with Docker and there are some kinks to figure out, but it's worth figuring out.

I haven't deployed with Docker yet but I plan to test that next once I've got local dev fully working as intended. It's optional though, you could always deploy with Git webhooks or whatever you were using up to now.